# Hyperledger fabric : How to set up a distributed network of peer nodes?

Tags: distributed-system, hyperledger-fabric, peer

How to set-up distributed system of peer nodes in different machines in hyperledger-fabric v1.0.0 beta ?

Comment: Here is the script https://github.com/yacovm/fabricDeployment allowing to setup and configure distributed Hyperledger Fabric setup for multiple nodes.

Comment: Hi subhra were you able to complete your setup?

Comment: No I was not able to do so

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you should define how is going to be your network, i.e. how many and wich nodes are going to be started up in each machine. Then, you should define the docker-compose files for each machine. There you define the nodes that you will put up in each machine.

At the end, you will start up the nodes.

Make sure that you define well the configuration of all the config files, especially the hosts.

Comment: So for 3 machines we will have 3 local docker compose file ? Can you send an example as in how you had implemented it ? How do these nodes connect to one channel ? Is it that from each machine we will have to create a cli container ?

Comment: I copy & paste the configuration file that you have in the docker-compose-cli.yaml file and the base/docker-compose-base.yaml file. I deleted the service and containers that I don't need in each machine. Then, you connect to the channel: 1) Via the definition of the Peers in the configtx.ymal; 2) Creating the channel; 3) At the end, each Peer joins the channel

Comment: Its not working since two network needs to be joined based on some common network. I tried that using docker swarm but the network driver is being reset to the default one . How to change that ? How did you set up the network without docker swarm ?

Comment: You have to comment the default network (byfn), and add a new property for each container: network_mode: host. Also, in the peer-base.yaml file, you should change the CORE_VM_DOCKER_HOSTCONFIG_NETWORKMODE=host. I need to read more about Docker ant its networks, I'm new on it. Probably it would be better if you used docker-machine.

Comment: @Urko could you please share you config files?

Comment: i am getting 
grpc: addrConn.resetTransport failed to create client transport: connection error: desc = "transport: Error while dialing dial tcp: lookup orderer.example.com on 127.0.1.1:53: no such host"; Reconnecting to {orderer.example.com:7050 <nil>}

Comment: Can your hosts communicate among them? Could you try to do a ping among then? Probably, you have to change your docker configuration. You can read more about it here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44775844/error-starting-up-a-network-nodes-in-different-vm-failed-connecting-to-ordere