# Hyperledger - Blockchain Peers not connecting - Docker container properties

Tags: docker, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I am creating a sample Blockchain network using tutorial https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.2/build_network.html. I am facing an error while connecting the peers :
`Error: failed to create deliver client: orderer client failed to connect to orderer.example.com:7050: failed to create new connection: context deadline exceeded.`

I found a probable solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44775844/error-starting-up-a-network-nodes-in-different-vm-failed-connecting-to-ordere) which I would like to test but I need help for below :

1. How to update default network of the containers
2. How to add property for each container.

While accessing my etc/docker directory I am getting error 'Server returned empty listing for directory '/etc/docker' and also it says permission denied when I try to access it from terminal. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for making any changes in Docker containers. I faced similar issue, you can clean up the system space or if you are using a VM you install a fresh network in a new VM(assuming you already have all configuration files copied).